# Notepad++ Replace random text

Tags: replace, notepad++

How can I change the following text:

```
<OurRef>14551783</OurRef>
<OurRef>14551423</OurRef>
<OurRef>05420404</OurRef>
```

To:

```
 <OurRef></OurRef>
 <OurRef></OurRef>
 <OurRef></OurRef>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Replace screen (Ctrl+H), select Regular expression under Search Mode. Then you can use pattern matching to replace `<OurRef>.*</OurRef>` with `<OurRef></OurRef>`.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

More geeky way would be replace `(?<=<OurRef>).*(?=</OurRef>)` by nothing.

In this case you are using lookbehind and lookahead assertions, which make more sense, since you are replacing exactly text you want, without touching tags.